# Combine multiple CSS Preprocessors

Tags: css, sass, less, stylus

We have a hundreds of .less files in production, but would like to start incorporating .scss files as well.

Would I need to make my own file type in order to compile mutliple types of CSS preprocessor files or is there already a way to do something like this:

```
@import 'less-styles.less';
@import 'scss-styles.scss';
@import 'stylus-styles.styl'; //potentially
```

whereby it produces a single CSS file in that order.

Comment: You should be able to just compile less, scss and stylus to css and then merge the files together in a second step

Comment: Are you including grunt or gulp in your build step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of valid CSS code is also valid Less code, you could compile your SCSS and stylus files first to CSS and import that.

```
sass scss-styles.scss scss-styles.css
```

Than in your Less code:

```
@import (less) scss-styles.css
```

The `less` keyword above does:

> less: treat the file as a Less file, no matter what the file extension

The above means that you can extend and mixin the CSS selectors from the `scss-styles.css` file  in your Less code.

Notice that variables and mixins from the from the `scss-styles.css` file are not available for (re)use in Less.

If you need the variables and mixins too, the only solution seems [to convert your SCSS to Less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872728/converting-sass-to-less/27326457#27326457). See also: https://github.com/bassjobsen/grunt-scss2less

You should be able to do the same for your stylus (.styl) files.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have not seen any tools that would allow developers to cross-reference LESS mixins from Sass, or versa-vice.

That doesn't mean that you can't use multiple preprocessors in the same site, it just means that you will be limited in how they can interact. With concatenation and minification tools you could certainly build LESS and Sass separately and then merge them into a single file that gets minified.

With all of that said, I highly discourage that approach. Pick a technology for the project, and stick with it. That way you can make the most of the tools at hand, and only have to worry about a single technology lifecycle (updates, API changes, etc).

Comment: The above only works when you don't want to reuse the code from the different preprocessors.

Comment: @BassJobsen, if you want to reuse the code from a different preprocessor, convert it.